# Why is this not including all files?

Tags: php, mysql

The code below is only including the first file. There are 2 files in total currently buy will be more in the future. How would I code it to include all files?

The code works but just includes 1 file, so it does not work the way it was intended to.

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT directory FROM modules WHERE enabled = {es} ORDER BY id ASC", 'yes');
$num = $result->numberOfRows;

while($row = $result->getArray())
{
  if($num != 0)
  { 
    if(file_exists($this->root . '/modules/' . $row['directory']))
    {
      include($this->root . '/modules/' . $row['directory'] . '/' . $row['directory'] . '.php');
    }
    else
    {
      $this->db->query("DELETE FROM modules WHERE directory = {es}", $row['directory']);
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** I found the problem. The files I was including have sql queries in them using the same variables "$result" and "$row". So when it included and executed the files then they were resetting each other.

Comment: there is no reason that it should include except the file doesn't exist or if the values in the db doesn't match the file.

Comment: im not sure. Try echoing $this->root . '/modules/' . $row['directory'] to ensure the pathing is correct. Also, why are you doing a check for num !=0, your while loop already handles that

Answer (score 0):

It looks akay. Did you check if the code in the loop is iterated over twice?

It could be that the first file that's included sets the value of `$num` to 0. If that happens, then the loop will continue, but the code including the modules is no longer executed. Anyway, this check isn't necessary. If the query doesn't return rows, then the loop condition should evaluate to false the first time already, so the `if` doesn't add any value.

Another problem could be that the file name name doesn't match. Maybe there's a typo, or the case doesn't match (Linux file names are case sensitive!). Try to use `require` instead of `include`. It will fail if a module cannot be found, so it gives you better information if that's the case.

Comment: Ok, I have removed the if($num != 0) and still no luck. Also I checked the database and the file names and paths and they are correct. It includes and executes correctly for the 1st item in the database, however it ignores the second. If I switch their id in the database(which the results are being ordered by), then it will execute whichever comes first and ignores the second. I hope I am being clear, please excuse me if I am not.